# PyQt5 Displaying an Image using a QLabel from Memory

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to display an image using a `QLabel` (called `myLabel` in the code snippet). `img_data` is binary data loaded from a database.
Because I couldn't figure out how to get a QPixmap straight from memory, I tried writing the image to a temporary file and loading that file in the QPixmap constructor.

```
import tempfile
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


try:
    img_data = load_operation_that_might_fail()
except:
    myLabel.setText("no image available")
    return

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("wb", prefix="qt-image-", suffix=".png") as file:
    file.write(img_data)
    file.flush()
    pixmap = QPixmap(file.name)
    myLabel.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

This works fine on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, but it doesn't work on Windows 10. On Windows it will properly display the `no image available`, but when an image is found the `QLabel` will just end up blank, displaying nothing at all.

Running python 3.7 on both operating systems with freshly installed `PyQt5` packages.

How do I make this work on Windows? Perhaps there is a more elegant approach that avoids writing a temporary file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the image from memory using `loadFromData`

In your example, the following should work:

```
try:
    img_data = load_operation_that_might_fail()
except:
    myLabel.setText("no image available")
    return

pixmap = QPixmap()
myLabel.loadFromData(img_data, 'png')
```

Here is a full example, just put an image in "c:/temp/test.png":

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(self.load_operation_that_might_fail(), 'png')

        lbl = QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.show()


    def load_operation_that_might_fail(self):
        with open('c:/temp/test.png', 'rb') as f:
            return f.read()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```